# Can any one give an idea about best way of implementing script in selenium web driver with testng and eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I have started writing selenium web driver script using with TestNg and Eclipse . Can any one suggest basic idea and better way of scripting ?

Currently i am working a big project which have so many modules. I have to automate some test case in all modules. So how will i start with ??

1, I have to create separate  class on writing script for each module ??

2, Since login script is common , how can i reuse its script on each module ??

Can any one share idea about creating classes and writing script and running it ??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to address your Questions one by one:

1. `I have to create separate class on writing script for each module` : A lot depends on how you design your framework. Now your framework can be [one of the following types](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/test-automation-frameworks-selenium-tutorial-20/):

a. Module Based Testing Framework

b. Library Architecture Testing Framework

c. Data Driven Testing Framework

d. Keyword Driven Testing Framework

e. Hybrid Testing Framework

f. Behavior Driven Development Framework

2. **How to select a framework?** A lot will depend on the functionalities your framework would perform. For example,

a. If your framework needs to test one by one component/module, `Module Based Testing Framework` should be your approach. `PageFactory` using POM is one of the best practice in-terms of performance & least maintenance.

b. If your framework needs to read real-time data from excel sheets, `Data Driven Testing Framework` should be your approach.

c. If you are reusing a number of methods repeatedly for Assertions, `Library Architecture Testing Framework` should be your approach.

d. If you want to leverage the benefits of all kinds of associated frameworks then `Hybrid Testing Framework` should be your approach.

Now depending on the design of the framework, you have to write scripts/class for each module/library.

3. `Since login script is common , how can i reuse its script on each module ??` : The answer to this question is situation dependent .If you follow `Data Driven Testing Framework` to read the different credentials from an excel file recursively, it would be a nice idea to create a separate library for that.
4. `Can any one share idea about creating classes and writing script and running it ??` : There is nothing exceptional in writing class or scripts. Choose a language of your choice among Java / Python / C# / Ruby and create your first script. There is a lot of documentation available within stackoverflow.com, github.com & other external sites.
5. Moving forward you may like to integrate `TestNG` to your framework which provides a lot of flexibility to work with viz `Annotations` and some superb Reporting Class.
6. Finally you can integrate the `Maven` framework to help you to gather all your required dependencies in quick time to execute your framework seamlessly.

Hope this answers all of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can google 'page factory' model as a methodology for your tests.   Alternatively nothing prohibits to setup one of your own; of course depending on the nature of the business/project you are working on.

Personally, I like having a TestBase class which holds major functionality (like findElement, or gotoPage, or typeChars) and then from there create a class per test case always extending the main TestBase (so you can inherit call its methods).

So to answer your questions:

1) It is really up to you, but you can write a class per test case where each @Test annotation will be a test step (so you can play with dependencies and priorities)

2) You can write up a loginViaEmail method/function in your TestBase and call it from every test on your @BeforeClass (so it loads up your config before you start each test). Something like this:

```
public void loginViaEmail(String email, String pass){

driver.navigate("https://yourhomepage.com");
findElement.by.xpath(loginButton).click();
// input credentials
// click login
}
```

Then you can go at your changePass test/class:

```
public class ChangePass extends TestBase {


    @BeforeClass
    public void intialSetup(){
    loginViaEmail("youremail@test.com", "someHardToGuessPass");
    }

    @Test public void findChangePassLink(){

    //rest of your test code
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, best of luck!